# enum colors with dynamic alpha value

Tags: ios, swift, enums

i'm have an enum Colors to return colors, I'm wondering if enum can achieve the changes of dynamic aplha?

```
enum Colors {

        case
         text,
         yesColorWith(alpha:CGFloat)


        var color: UIColor {
            switch self {
            case .text: return UIColorFromHEX(0xd1d1d1, alpha: 1.0)
            case .yesColorWith(alpha: CGFloat) : return UIColorFromHEX(0x89A225, alpha: alpha)
            }
        }
    }


func UIColorFromHEX(_ hex: UInt, alpha:Float) -> UIColor {

        return UIColor(
            red: CGFloat((hex >> 16) & 0xff) / 255,
            green: CGFloat((hex >> 08) & 0xff) / 255,
            blue: CGFloat((hex >> 00) & 0xff) / 255,
            alpha: CGFloat(alpha))
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the wild and wacky world of Swift `case` patterns. Change

```
case .yesColorWith(alpha: CGFloat) :
```

to

```
case .yesColorWith(let alpha) :
```

Thus:

```
enum Colors {
    case text
    case yesColorWith(alpha: CGFloat)
    var color: UIColor {
        switch self {
        case .text:
            return UIColorFromHEX(0xd1d1d1, alpha: 1.0)
        case .yesColorWith(let alpha): // <-*
            return UIColorFromHEX(0x89A225, alpha: alpha)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be divided by 255 ?

Comment: no - just use alpha from 0 to 1 - the 256 ist to change the (hex) range from 0...255 to 0...1 by deviding by 256

Comment: @muescha 255 it is the maximum value (FF). 255 / 256 is less than 1.0 so you will never have a solid color there.

Comment: Boys, boys, calm down. Look, I've deleted it entirely. That's not what my answer is about. It's about the `case let` syntax.

Comment: Nitpicking side note: The parameter label in the declaring `case` line is negligible. It's not related to the `let` variable in the `switch` scope at all.

Comment: @muescha yea, the question is not about the color value but how to set dymanic alpha :) anyway i added my func to return colors.

Comment: all is ok :) @Leo: i mix the 256 with the 255. in code it is correct with 255. Desmont: i answer only for the question of Leo "Shouldn't it be divided by 255" :)